# Unnecessary space before the full stop

Tags: spacing

I am facing some spacing issues in `LaTeX`. Using this code:

```
    \documentclass[numbers,sort&compress]{IntechOpen-Book}%%OPTIONS are numbers, authoryear, sort&compress,sectref
    \usepackage{physics}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{svg}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{placeins}
    \graphicspath{{Artworks/}}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \Mainmatter
    
    \begin{frontmatter}
    
    \chapter{Title}
    % Enter author names EXACTLY as you would like them to appear in the final manuscript
    \author{Author 1}
    
    
    \makechaptertitle
    
    \chaptermark{Chapter Title (will appear in header)}
    
    \begin{abstract} % abstract = max 200 words, unstructured format
    The abstract MUST be \textbf{unstructured} and briefly introduce the manuscript, not exceeding \textbf{200 words}. Citations should NOT be included in the abstract.
    
    \end{abstract}
    
    \begin{keywords} % use a minimum of 5 kwrds, separate them with a comma
    kwrd 1, kwrd 2
    \end{keywords}
    
    
    \end{frontmatter}
    
    \section{Introduction} % first section MUST be titled Introduction, and feature introductory text; do NOT change this title
    
    \section{Data}
    probability equal to the square of the magnitude of the basis state coefficient, i.e., $p_0 = \abs{h_0}^2$, and $p_1 = \abs{j_1}^2$, see  Eq. \eqref{eq:Measurement}. 
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:Measurement}
        P(\psi_1) =
        \begin{bmatrix*}
            k_0 \\
            z_1
        \end{bmatrix*} =
        \begin{bmatrix*}
            \abs{r_0}^2 \\
            \abs{g_1}^2
        \end{bmatrix*}    =
        \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=2em]{image.png}}}
    \end{equation}
    
    % \begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt} % Specify the bibliography style
    
    \bibliography{refs}
    
    
    
    % \end{thebibliography}
    
    
    
    \end{document}
```

I am getting the following PDF:

[image]

How can I remove the unnecessary space before the full stop?

Comment: Please provide the code which can not only be compiled but also reproduce the problem as shown in the picture.

Comment: Thank you @Stephen for the response. I have edited the question to provided you the .tex file code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off topic: in your preamble, dont load neither `graphicx` nor `amsmath` twice. Furthermore : (1) `amssymb` automatically loads `amsfonts` hence no need to load the latter. (2) `mathtools`  loads `amsmath`, hence in you load the former there mo need to load the latter.

Comment: *Off topic contimued* In your code (3) the two first `\documentclass` optioms are intended to be passed to `natbib`, likely loaded by your class; hence it would be more consistent to use a natbib-enabled bibstyle like `unsrtnat`on place of `unsrt`. (4) the construct `\begin{bmatrix*}` with the star is a `mathtools`-enhanced matrix environment intended to control the horizontal alignmemnt inside it, with an optional argument `[l]` , `[r]` or `[c]` that you omit,  hence `\begin{bmatrix}` would be better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The document class does

```
   1526 \@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}{%
   1527 \def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)\hskip12pt}}%
   1528 }{}
```

(line numbers are for reference) and the `\hskip12pt` is obviously the cause of your problem.

Fix by detaching `\eqref` from the equation numbering.

```
\documentclass[numbers,sort&compress]{IntechOpen-Book}
\usepackage{showframe} % just to show the margins

%%% FIX
\makeatletter
% detach \eqref and \tag making
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\eqreftagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\def\eqreftagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
\makeatother
%%%

\begin{document}

\Mainmatter

\begin{frontmatter}

\chapter{Title}
% Enter author names EXACTLY as you would like them to appear in the final manuscript
\author{Author 1}


\makechaptertitle

\chaptermark{Chapter Title (will appear in header)}

\begin{abstract} % abstract = max 200 words, unstructured format
The abstract MUST be \textbf{unstructured} and briefly introduce the manuscript, 
not exceeding \textbf{200 words}. Citations should NOT be included in the abstract.

\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords} % use a minimum of 5 kwrds, separate them with a comma
kwrd 1, kwrd 2
\end{keywords}


\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}

\section{Data}

Some words before the equation~\eqref{test}. Here it is
\begin{equation}\label{test}
1+1=2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @egreg for the great help.

Comment: @SarikaSingh In hindsight, I understood a possible reason for the class to do that redefinition and so I provided a different solution.